# Segmentation Fault (segfault) when using OGR CreateField() in Python

Tags: python, cartography, ogr

Receiving a segfault when running this very short script in Ubuntu.

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr

shpfile = 'Census_County_TIGER00_IN.shp'

def cust_field(field):
    '''cust_field(shpfile, field) creates a field definition, which, by calling cust_field(), can be used to create a field using the CreateField() function.
    cust_field() DOES NOT create a field -- it simply creates a "model" for a field, that can then be called later. It's weird, but that's GDAL/OGR, as far as I can tell.'''
    fieldDefn = ogr.FieldDefn(field, ogr.OFTInteger)
    fieldDefn.SetWidth(14)
    fieldDefn.SetPrecision(6)
    return fieldDefn

ds = ogr.Open(shpfile, 1)
lyr = ds.GetLayerByIndex(0)
field = cust_field("Test")
lyr.CreateField(field)
```

Everything runs smoothly until that last line, when iPython, normal shell Python and the IDLE command line all dump to a segmentation fault. Is this an error on my end or an issue with the underlying C that I'm not addressing properly?

Answer (score 2):

This looks ok to me.  I tried the script on a shapefile of mine and it seems to have worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Same here: it works when used on some shp.
I add such a problem once and was able to debug it using gdb (some python object got gc'ed but underlying C library was still using pointers to some fields of the object).